# How can I iterate through every single HTML element on a web page

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I currently have this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


$(this).each(function(index) {

    delete style;

    var style = $(this).attr("style");

    document.write(style);

));

});
```

However this is not working :/ Just keeps telling me `style` is undefined. Not quite sure where to go from there.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't even know if the above will work at all, but make sure you declare and or define variables before you try to use them. IE: Move `delete style` after `var style = ...` Just so you know, `delete` are for arrays and objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('*').each(function() {
  var style = $(this).attr("style");
  document.write(style); // better replace to console.debug(style); with Firebug installed
})
```

Edit: You certainly don't need the `delete style` statement, that's the error source.

Comment: In what browser does `delete` on a undefined variable cause an error?  I don't think this is what the OP wants, since `document.write` after load clears the existing page.

Comment: Right, code looks like being written for an experiment, in this case I'd use the `console.debug` instead of `document.write`. The browser is IE

Answer (score 0):

```
$('*').each(function() {
  document.write(this.style);
  //or console.log(this.style)
});
```

FYI
**this.style** refers to the element's style object.
**$(this).attr('style')** will pull the element's INLINE style

Answer (score 0):

It tells you that style is undefined because when you do `delete style;`, the variable style has not been defined.

You can select everything using `$('*')`

Iterate through your elements the way you already do it, it's fine. What exactly are you trying to do with the delete though?

```
$('*').each(function() {
  var style = $(this).attr("style");
  document.write(style);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).find('*').each(function()
{
 $(this).removeAttr('style');
});
```